# Expression to change format of a date in azure data factory (SQL Server source)?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I currently use the following SSIS expression to format a date in a certain way needed for processing. A common one is using the T-SQL function `GETDATE` like this:

```
((DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("yyyy", GETDATE())) + (RIGHT("00" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("mm", GETDATE()), 2))
```

That would turn today's date into an int like this: 202303

However, in azure data factory, I am trying to re-create this derived column data flow task, but this expression isn't supported. I'm not too familiar with adf's expression language. Anyone able to help me figure out how this *should* be done in adf? TY!

I googled, looked at the expression white papers, but can't see how this would be done in adf's expression language.

Answer (score 0):

> That would turn today's date into an int like this: 202303

You can use the below expression in the derived column of dataflow to get the above result.

```
toInteger(concat(toString(year(currentDate('UTC'))),split(toString(currentDate('UTC')),'-')[2]))
```

**My Sample:**

[image]

**(OR)**

You can try like this also.

```
toInteger(concat(split(toString(currentDate('UTC')),'-')[1],split(toString(currentDate('UTC')),'-')[2]))
```

[image]